# Display JSON Value from URL using PHP

Tags: php, json

How does one display the USD exchange rate from https://bitpay.com/api/rates using PHP on a web page?

ie, that in the first line:

```
{"code":"USD","name":"US Dollar","rate":325.8}
```

Comment: Step 1) Write some code.

Comment: It's json... so you would just use [`json_decode()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on that... it should put it into an array.  depending on your version of php, pay attention to the optional parameter(s).

Comment: cant figure out what u need. pls make ur problem and requirements clear.

Comment: You need to look into [Curl](http://codular.com/curl-with-php) and what @gloomy.penguin said. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) from php
it will convert the json data to a php object

but as suggested by Marc B 
write some code

Comment: $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://bitpay.com/api/rates"), true);
echo 'usd rate - ' . $jsonData[0]["rate"];

Comment: the answer is above.. the key is to add the "true"

Comment: glad it helped :) but what's the use of `var_dump` here?

Comment: it doesn't help.. just for working out what to do.. thanks.